# How to sum a column in dataframe using R

Tags: r, sum

```
A   Sum
2   2
3   5
4   9
5   14
```

If I have a dataframe with column A, and want to get column Sum, which is the sum of the previous observations in A. How could I do that using R? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you man. But it returns NA, not the right number.

Comment: Yes, it returns number, but not the right number. <_>

Comment: not sure if I am getting your question right? so you are looking for the sum of the column or for the cumulated sum? look up `sum()` and `cumsum()`and use `na.rm=T` if you have NA values

Comment: I want to compute the column of Sum. For instance, for row 2, 5=3+2.  Hope I have made it clear. I will look up those functions. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Got it! mydata$Sum <- cumsum(mydata[,"A"])

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `cumsum` (*cumulative sum*) function does.

```
A = 1:20
cumsum(A)
# [1]   1   3   6  10  15  21  28  36  45  55  66  78  91 105 120 136 153 171 190 210
```

In a data frame

```
df = data.frame(A = 1:20)
df$Sum = cumsum(df$A)
```